# Is continuity characteristic required for two equations to be equal

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

The function below is *discontinuous*:
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2-9}{x-3}
$$

But when it is further simplified, it becomes *continuous*:
$$
g(x)=x+3
$$

First question, is $f(x) = g(x)$ ? Second question, if presented with $f(x)$, is it mathematically incorrect to further simplify it?

Comment: Your function is not dicontinuous. It's of course continuous on the definition domain, i.e. on $\mathbb R-\{3\}$. If you define $f$ as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-9}{x-3}&x\neq 3\\ 6&x=3\end{cases},$$ then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, and obviously, $f(x)=g(x)$ on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **The function $g$ is a continuous extension of $f$.**

I will assume that the domain $D$ satisfies $3\in D$. The functions are not equal at $3$, $f(3)\neq g(3)$, since $f(3)$ is not defined. However $f$ has a removable discontinuity. In this case look at the [Riemann extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem):

---

Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ be an open subset of the complex plane, $a\in D$ a point of $D$ and $f(a)$ holomorphic function defined on the set $D\setminus \{a\}$. The following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is holomorphically extendable over $a$.
2. $f$ is continuously extendable over $a$
3. There exists a neighborhood of $a$ on which $f$ is bounded.
4. $\lim\limits_{z\to a}(z - a) f(z) = 0$

---

We will trivially prove that our function meets the fourth condition:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 3}\,(x - 3) \frac{x^2-9}{x-3}=\lim\limits_{x\to 3}x^2-9=3^2-9=0.$$
Now by the Riemann extension theorem we can conclude that $f$ is continuously (even holomorphically) extendable over $3$. And this extension is $g(x)=x+3$.

Comment: Thank you. All posted answers are very helpful and correct answers. I am choosing this one as the most correct as it introduces the concept of Riemann's theorem on how to further explore the subject. Mind blown.

Answer (score 3):

If the domain is the set of real numbers, no, $f(x) \neq g(x)$. Even though $f$ simplifies to $g$, $f$ is a rational function, and $g$ is a linear function. Because $(x - 3)$ is a factor on both numerator and denominator, $x = 3$ does not belong on the domain of $f$, and it does on the domain of $g$.

If you are graphing $f$ and $g$, they will look almost the same, but for $f$, $x = 3$ is a hole.

This is called a removable discontinuity. See [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html) from WolframAlpha for more information.

Comment: This answer is consistent to my recent findings with my `TI NSpire CX CAS II` graphing calculator there is indeed a hole. Your statements is also what the `TC7 by Leithold` on page 8. To my 2nd question, is it then mathematically incorrect to simplify `f(x)` further?

Comment: Simplifying $f$ means that we are assuming that $x - 3 \neq 0$, because of the fact that we can't divide by zero. In this case, it is incorrect to simplify $f$ because the domain is the set of real numbers, which includes $3$. However, if you are to take the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $3$, then yes, you can simplify it to solve for the limit.

Answer (score 3):

First question. For which $x$? We have something like
$$f : \mathbb R\setminus \{3\} \to \mathbb R\quad\mbox{and}\quad g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R $$
If you ask if $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$, then that is false, because $f(3)$ is not defined. You can define $f(3)$ such that the extension is continuous. Just because there is a canonical way to extend $f$, does not mean you can't define $f(3) = 1000$, for instance.

Second question. Not incorrect. By definition of $f$ the quantity $x-3$ is always non-zero. Thus we can simplify.

Title question. Yes, two functions are equal if and only if they have the same domain $X$, same codomain and $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x\in X$. Thus, if one of them is continuous, so must the other.

The functions $f$ and $g$ are equivalent, because they are equal almost everywhere. But this equivalence need not maintain continuity.

Answer (score 1):

for the first question :

$\frac{x^2-9}{x-3}$=$x+3$

$x^2-9$ = $(x+3)(x-3)$

$x^2-9$= $x^2-9$

$f(x)$=$g(x)$   $∀ x≠ 3$

Comment: Thanks. The part which confuses me here, is that, `the act of simplification` is being prohibited because it seems there is a need `to retain` or preserve the discontinuity in `f(x)`, which is lost when it is simplified in `g(x)`. Now, I can arbitrarily and easily sprinkle any equation for it to have a denominator of `x-123` and this makes the equation unequal..